# How to use nested for-loops to output power table in java?

Tags: java, loops

I want to output the power table from n (0) to n (10) with just the base being inputted using the scanner.

For now, I am having difficulties in setting it up

Code:

```
    else if (option == 2){
            int base = keyboard.nextInt();
            for (int x = base; x <= base; x++){
                System.out.print(base+"^");
                for (int y = 0; y <= 10; y++){ // "y" is exponent
                    System.out.print(y+"=");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Sample input:

```
 2 (option ##)
 5 (base)
```

Expected Output:

```
 5^0=
 5^1=
 5^2=
 5^3=
 - - - several lines are skipped here - - -
 5^10=
```

Note: This is not the expected output, but I want to try out the code by myself this is just the step that would take me to the end result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = keyboard.nextInt();
        int base = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (option == 2) {
            for (int exponent = 0; exponent <= 10; exponent++) {
                int result = 1;// Reset result for each exponent
                for (int i = 1; i <= exponent; i++) {
                    result *= base;
                }
                System.out.println(base + "^" + exponent + "=" + result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
2
5
5^0=1
5^1=5
5^2=25
5^3=125
5^4=625
5^5=3125
5^6=15625
5^7=78125
5^8=390625
5^9=1953125
5^10=9765625
```

Comment: Yes this works, but i want to display the expanded form too, like the other question i asked you, if the exponent is less than 1 it displays no expanded forms, only if its greater than 2, it displays the expanded form respectively

Comment: Nvm I figured that part out but thanks for ur help!

Comment: Could you upvote this rq I am having trouble in asking questions again like it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61643733/how-to-keep-the-letter-the-user-inputs-and-hide-all-the-other-characters-with-a